# Is it possible to use the values method for a HashMap if the values are ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I'm stuck trying to get something to work in an assignment. I have a `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Object>>` called `sharedLocks` and I want to check whether a certain value can be found in any ArrayList in the HashMap.

The following code obviously wouldn't work because `Object[]` can't be cast to `ArrayList[]`, but it is a demonstration of the general functionality that I want.

```
ArrayList[] values = (ArrayList[]) sharedLocks.values().toArray();
boolean valueExists = false;
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i].contains(accessedObject)) {
        valueExists = true;
    }
}
```

Is there a way for me to check every ArrayList in the HashMap for a certain value? I'm not sure how to use the values method for HashMaps in this case.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`HashMap.values()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values%28%29) returns a `Collection`. You can iterate through the collection without having to convert it to an array (or list).

```
for (ArrayList<Object> value : sharedLocks.values()) {
...
}
```

Comment: @Vipar this is in no way different from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10602913/829571)... You still need to check `if(value.contains(...))`

Comment: I couldn't edit my comment.
What I meant was, that what he said was right, but he still uses a foreach loop, which he put in after I wrote my answer :)

Comment: @Vipar FYI, If you hover your mouse over your comment, a cross should appear that you can click to delete it.

Comment: Still new to the site. Thanks for the tip though :)

Answer (score 1):

A HashMap is a bit special, in that it doesn't really have an index to go by at all...

What you want to do, is turn the HashMap into a collection first, and then iterate through the collection with an iterator.

Whenever you get hold of an ArrayList in the HashMap, you cycle through every element in the arrayList, and then you jump out if you find it :)

Answer (score 0):

**Use the `toArray` method which takes an array as an argument.**

This uses the array you specify to fill the data, and maintains the typing so you don't need to typecast.  Additionally, you should keep the generic `<Object>` in the definition.

```
ArrayList<Object>[] values =
     sharedLocks.values().toArray(new ArrayList<Object>[sharedLocks.size()]);
```

One more thing to consider is if multiple threads can modify this `HashMap`.  In this case, you will want to synchronize this line of code to the `HashMap` and make sure all modifications are also synchronized.  This will make sure that other threads won't modify the contents between the `.size()` call and the `.toArray()` call, which is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need arrays:

```
boolean valueExists = false;
for (ArrayList<Object> value : sharedLocks.values()) {
    if (value.contains(accessedObject)) {
        valueExists = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because a Foreach loop is designed to run an action on every element in a collection, whereas a for loop can be broken out of because the amount of elements you have to look through is uncertain.

Comment: @Vipar So how would you rewrite the snippet in this answer?

Comment: @Vipar although it is true in general, I think this is the very one situation where it makes sense to use it. Actually even better would be to create a method that returns true if the value exists and the `break;` would become `return true;`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just iterate through  all the values in the map:

```
for (ArrayList<Object> list : sharedLocks) {
  if (list.contains(accessedObject)) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: It's generally bad practice to break out of a foreach loop

Comment: You will have to break out of it, when you found what you were looking for. Else it's kinda pointless.

Comment: You don't _have_ to (although I agree it is more efficient if you do)

Answer (score 0):

heres a link to an example of iterating though a hash map. Use this to pull out each arraylist and in turn extend this to then search each element of the array list for the given entry.

http://www.java-examples.com/iterate-through-values-java-hashmap-example

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use a nested foreach loop.

```
foreach(every element in the hashmap) {
 foreach(every element in arraylist) {
   // do comparision
 }
}
```

you might just get away with a foreach loop and a keyExists() call or something within it. I cannot recall the API off the top of my head.